# Using autoresizing masks for multiple iOS app

Tags: ios

Say I want to write an app which users of iOS5, iOS6 and iOS7 should be able to use.

Is it OK if I use autoresizing masks (springs and struts)? Will this not cause some issues
for people having iOS7?

because if I use autolayout I'll have to make it backwards compatible with iOS5 and I don't want it yet.

Answer (score 1):

iOS will still translate the autoresizingMasks to constraints, because all older apps would break otherwise. I would still recommend testing your app on an iOS 7 device before releasing it, but using autoResizingMasks should work.